# ListView problem

Tags: android, listview

I have an image of some restaurant and under that some info of that restaurant. Under all of that i have some listView with some menu (what is on discount)... My problem is this: Before listView i have an textView with a description of that restaurant. It can be different sizes for different restaurants, and because of that sometimes my listView isn't showing on screen. I tried to put ScrollView, but it was bad idea... What can I do??? ANy sugestion??? Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:weightSum="100"
  android:keepScreenOn="true">
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="50"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOne1">
      <ImageView  android:layout_width="0dip" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:src="@drawable/marker_a" 
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"                 
                    >
        </ImageView>
  </LinearLayout> 
  <ScrollView     
    android:id="@+id/widgetOne"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:text="Ime restorana" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewImeRestorana" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#5E5E5E">
        </TextView>
        <TextView   android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewAdresa" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>
         <TextView   android:text="@string/daljina" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewDaljina" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>
         <TextView  
            android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewNista" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>
         <TextView   android:text="@string/radno_vreme_" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewRadnoVreme" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>         
         <TextView   android:text="@string/pon_nedelja" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewPonSub" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>         
         <TextView   android:text="Nedelja" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewNedelja" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>
         <TextView    android:text="@string/pozovite_nas_" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewPozovite" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
         </TextView>
         <Button  android:text="Pozovi" 
            android:id="@+id/buttonPozovi" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"                                         
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <TextView   android:text="Opis" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewOpis" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"     
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"                                     
            android:background="@drawable/border">
        </TextView> 
        <TextView   android:text="@string/specijalna_ponuda" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewSpecijalnaPonuda" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp">
        </TextView> 
        <TextView   android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/textViewPonudeNema" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="14sp">
        </TextView> 
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView                
                android:id="@+id/listViewPonuda" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:visibility="visible"                                
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:textSize="14sp">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>           
  </LinearLayout>       
  </ScrollView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use the listview header and footer concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing `ListView` or `ScrollView` on another List/ScrollView doesn't work properly.
You can use [ListView#addHeaderView(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) to add the description of the restaurant. This behaves as one more row at the top of the list which doesn't need to be similar to the other rows defined in adapter.

Comment: You didn't understand me...description (of restaurant) is above listView and it changes sizes...because of that, in some cases i cant see my listView and sometimes textView before listView(android:id="@+id/textViewPonudeNema")... Can i with addHeader add more than one view??? I ask this because i add one header before, and than set adapter in listView...

Comment: 1)"...in some cases i cant see my listView..." - you'll be able to scroll your `ListView` (along with its header) down to see its items. If you don't like this anyway, you should reconsider your description layout to make it smaller. 2) You can add as many headers with that method as you want. They could be scrolled as the regular list items.

Comment: How can i do that??? Can i use for loop which will go through my list and create some header which i will add to listView? Do i create header programmaticly or in xml??? Do you have some example?

Comment: Well it seems that you were right and I havn't got your question. Why do you need for loop? Do you need a header for any list item?

Comment: okay..i have image which takes half of my screen. On the other half of the screen i must put 11 textViews and 1 button and under all that i have listView where i put some products from database. I dont know how much will be high my listView. Happens next: sometimes i see listView, sometimes i dont. This depends of one textView where i put some text from database. That text can be very long and then i cant see listView...how to put everything in half of the screen???

Comment: Then you probably just need to set `layout_weight=1` for both views in your `LinearLayout`. They will take equal space.

Comment: This didn't helped me...i put the image on 45% of screen and rest on 55%...this looks okey now...i will try to find some phones to test it...thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

In you xml file you used the layourt height as fill_parent in the inner layout.So that it behaves like that.

try this code

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="Vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:weightSum="100"
  android:keepScreenOn="true">
  <ImageView  
   android:layout_width="0dip" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:src="@drawable/marker_a" 
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:scaleType="fitStart"
   android:layout_gravity="center"                 
   />
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView android:text="Ime restorana" 
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewImeRestorana" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#5E5E5E">
    </TextView>
    <TextView   android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewAdresa" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>
     <TextView   android:text="@string/daljina" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewDaljina" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>
     <TextView  
        android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewNista" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>
     <TextView   android:text="@string/radno_vreme_" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewRadnoVreme" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>         
     <TextView   android:text="@string/pon_nedelja" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewPonSub" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>         
     <TextView   android:text="Nedelja" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewNedelja" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>
     <TextView    android:text="@string/pozovite_nas_" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewPozovite" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>
     <Button  android:text="Pozovi" 
        android:id="@+id/buttonPozovi" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"                                         
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
    <TextView   android:text="Opis" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewOpis" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"     
        android:textColor="#5E5E5E"                                     
        android:background="@drawable/border">
    </TextView> 
    <TextView   android:text="@string/specijalna_ponuda" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewSpecijalnaPonuda" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp">
    </TextView> 
    <TextView   android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/textViewPonudeNema" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="14sp">
    </TextView> 
    <ListView                
            android:id="@+id/listViewPonuda" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:visibility="visible"                                
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>       
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: then set the imageview height in  pixel(example android:layout_height="150dip")

Comment: but then in phones that have biger screen image will be smaler than a rest of my textViews...any other sugestion???

Comment: In run time get the bitmap which you want to assign and set the imageview height.Example imageview.setHeight(bitmap.getHeight());  Now the Height will chnage automatically depend upon the bitmap

Comment: images are always the same height...they are taken with camera and are the same size, same resolution....